# Setting up Users to be able to only add/edit users they have set up.

Tags: users, user-groups

I don't think this is currently possible. But maybe someone has done this already as a plugin or would I need to build one?

Situation is I need to set up First level Users who would be able to set up and manage other level 2 users. But only users they have set up themselves in a specified user group.

So as an example:

Level1 User1 sets up Level2 User1 & User2

Level1 User2 sets up Level2 User3 & User4

Level2 users are auto assigned to a Group called Guests.

So when Level1 User1 logs in he can only see, add and manage Level2 users in the Guests group that he has set up. i.e. Level2 User1 & User2.